# How to convert willpopscope to popscope with pop data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following code that is deprecated now i want to convert it in popscope.

```
    WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          bool canPop = true;
          if (canPop) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop("flag");
          }
          return canPop;
        },
    )
```

I want to convert the above code in popscope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can view the docs on it : [popScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html)

but the actual code after deprecation will be like this :

```
        PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
            if (didPop) {
              return;
            }
            //show some dialog;
          },
          child:
 //your widget
        ),
```

the `canpop` disables system back gestures.

the `onpopInvoked` will controls what happens if the user get back like if you want to show a dialog or smth

Comment: okay how to add this line?  `Navigator.of(context).pop("flag");`

Comment: replace it where i have put `//show some dialog`

Comment: how to show dialog and let the user select whether they want to exit or not?

Comment: @MunsifAli also show the dialog by `showDialog` function replacing `//show some dialog`

Comment: how to close the app when user click yes.